# HSQL db not initializing from data.sql in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I have created an API using Spring Boot, and when I run it, I am able to execute CRUD commands as expected. However, my data.sql file is not being used to pre-populate my in-memory database. Can anyone provide any insights on how to fix this? Here are the applicable configurations I'm using:

```
pom.xml

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
application.properties

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: What code or configuration do you have that makes you think `data.sql` should be read? This name does not pop up anywhere in your snippets.

Comment: Your properties look good for me. Where did you put the `data.sql` file? Is it on the classpath? Like in `src/main/resources`

Comment: I put the data.sql file in src/main/resources/

Comment: Where is the code that deals with the sql script?